# Azure Blob Storage Print all the files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, printing

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC4 Application. I am uploading files to Azure Blob Storage. Is there a way to print multiple blob storage files at a time? Suppose i uploaded 25 files to Blob storage. I want to print all 25 files at a time. Either directly send to printer or show in a pdf file for printing. There are Image,xlsx,doc files are there.

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since Blob Storage is a simple object store, in order to print the blobs or do any conversion you would need to download the blobs somewhere - it could be on your local computer or a VM.

Comment: Is it possible to print all the blobs at the same time. let us say i have 25 blobs attached to 1 invoice. Is it possible to send it to printer all the blobs instead of downloading and printing 1 by 1. ?

Comment: You could just download all blobs which are needed on your local computer and send all files to the printer.